# Getting a driver for a NETGEAR A6201 WiFi USB Adapter

Tags: drivers, wireless, usb

I just set up my computer with one hard drive dedicated to Ubuntu and another  dedicated to Windows. I did this so that I can learn Ubuntu and decide if I want to stick with it. I have a NETGEAR A6201 WiFi USB Adapter that is my only source for accessing the Internet. It is not natively supported by Ubuntu but I found the driver on GitHub. I want to know if it is possible to download the driver from GitHub onto a USB flash drive and then use this drive to install the driver on Ubuntu.

Comment: It is possible to download a zip file from github and copy to Ubuntu and install if some packages like build-essential and possibly dkms are installed already

Comment: *build-essential* and *dkms* and all their dependecies are on the original DVD or USB from which you installed Ubuntu. Do you still have it? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 I dont have the original USB but would it work to make a new USB install and then use that one or do I have to reset the drive and start from scratch. And all I would have to do is `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install build-essential`?

Comment: Make a new one and hold on to it until I propose an answer. No, it will not be that easy as `apt install` however, if you haven't any other connectivity, my method is the easist way.

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for a proven reliable way to use USB drive as an apt repository and simply apt-get install the driver. I have, so far, been unsuccessful. I propose another method that will get the prerequisite *build-essential* installed.

This method, although it is tedious, will work. The list of deb files you need is this (with the exception of bcmwl-kernel-source): https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/GbZ689gYXw/

Create a folder on your desktop to hold the files. I suggest:

```
mkdir ~/Desktop/debs
```

Browse the USB drive and look in pool/main/b for build-essential; in pool/main/d for dkms and dpkg-dev; in pool/main/f for fakeroot and so on. Continue until every package on the list I provided is dragged into the debs folder.

Now, back to the terminal:

```
cd ~/Desktop/debs
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

**EDIT**: Now let’s install the driver. Please download this file and transfer it to the desktop of the Ubuntu machine: https://github.com/kaduke/Netgear-A6210/archive/port-to-4.15.zip

Right-click it and select ‘Extract here.’ Now back to the terminal:

```
cd ~/Desktop/Netgear-A6210-port-to-4.15
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe mt7662u_sta
```

Your wireless should now be working.

Please tell me how it proceeds; I will probably have one final step.

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/h4NczktGCZ/

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: it appears to be working perfectly I will update if anything goes wrong

Comment: It worked for most of the night then randomly stoped detecting the device uppon reboot the device was detected but no wifi networks appear

Comment: Is the module loaded? `lsmod | grep mt7` Any clues in the log? `dmesg | grep -e mt7 -e wlx`