# Installing realtek RTL8812 driver for ac 1200 inamax dongle

Tags: drivers, wireless, realtek

I am almost completely computer illiterate. I am attempting to repurpose an old computer for very limited use and need to access the internet wirelessly for my purposes. I have successfully installed Xubuntu onto the desktop and need to install the drivers (which I possess in disc form that came with the dongle and the disc does contain a driver file for Linux-based systems) to access my wireless network. I do not have a wired internet connection to access the internet. I do have the original install disc. The dongle was successfully installed onto the same computer on the Windows XP operating system immediately prior to installing Xubuntu.

How do I prompt the driver files to run? The file name is:

RTL88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.1.7_19806

within this file are the files:

[image: screenshot]

Below is a screenshot of the terminal emulator with the commands entered that I was requested to provide:

[image: terminal emulator screenshot]

Build essentials package:

[image: build essentials package screenshot]

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of these terminal commands: `lsb_release -d` and, with the wireless dongle inserted: `lsusb` You can open a terminal with Ctrl+Alt+t. Do you still have your original Ubuntu install USB or DVD? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 The requested edits to the post have been made.

Answer (score 0):

In order to compile a kernel module, in this case a wireless driver, in Ubuntu requires the source code for the driver, which you have, as well as several build tools. If you could get a temporary internet connection by ethernet from a friend or by tethering your phone, installing the prerequisites is quite simple. From the terminal:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential
```

Without the possibility of a temporary connection, it will be necessary to go here: http://packages.ubuntu.com Find and downlad on some other computer all of the necessary packages and their dependencies. Transfer them on a USB key or similar. The process and a handy list are here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2439074&p=13940917#post13940917 Although the package bcmwl-kernel-source is included on the list, it is not required in this case.

Once all of the packages are installed without error, you are ready to compile the driver. From the terminal:

```
cd ~/Downloads/RTL88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.1.7_19806
chmod +x install.sh
sudo ./install.sh
```

Assuming that install process completed without error, load the module:

```
sudo modprobe 882xbu
```

Your wireless should now be working.

NOTE: I have some suspicion that this relatively old (2016) driver may not compile correctly in Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS. If it does not, I will have an alternative solution.

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the build essentials files you requested. Do I need all of the "other packages related to build essentials" that are on the left side of the page? I downloaded the [build-essential_12.4ubuntu1.tar.gz] file on the right.

Comment: I have the ability to tether my phone to the computer. Xubuntu sees the device but will not connect. I am unsure how to get it to connect.

Comment: You need everything on the list at the paste in the link I gave with the exception of bcmwl-kernel-source. Aslo, you need to click on amd64 in the page you screensotted and find a link to download the deb file. You do NOT want the tar.gz. Also, I meant the install USB or DVD that you used to install Ubuntu; NOT the CD that contains the driver for the wireless dongle. Do you have it? All of the required debs are on it, if you do.

Comment: yes I have the Xubuntu install disc.

Comment: This post describes the general process: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1080706/getting-a-driver-for-a-netgear-a6201-wifi-usb-adapter/1080722#1080722 I believe that all of the deb files I listed in the paste are on the Xubuntu install disc.

Answer (score 0):

The advice chili555 provided was good and accurate. The problem turned out to be more than I as a casual pc user was able to tackle. The main problem stemmed from installing and attempting to update the operating system without an ethernet connection. Luckily I had access to an experienced Linux programmer who was able to update my operating system and install the drivers for my dongle. The pc and wireless internet now works great!

IF YOU ARE NOT EXPERIENCED WITH UBUNTU MAKE SURE YOU HAVE A HARD WIRED ETHERNET CONNECTION BEFORE YOU INSTALL!!